# Virtual Address Translation Tips

Tags: operating-system, virtualization

I am preparing for an OS exam and I came across the following exercise:

You're given a 16-bit big-endian system. It supports memory management with a one-level page table. Page size is 1KByte. The least-significant bit is the valid bit. The second least significant bit is the modified bit.

These entries are currently in the page table:

```
0x2C00
0x0403
0xCC01
0x0000
0x7C01
```

I need to translate the following (if possible) to physical addresses: 0xB85, 0x1420, 0x1000, 0xC9A.

I've been reading up on the subject of virtual to physical memory translations but I'm still not clear how to do it for this particular example.

Since the system supports 16-bit addresses, that would mean 4 bits are for the page number, 10 are offset and 2 are the valid/dirty ones, correct?

Thus from this point, how does one get to convert the virtual addresses into physical ones?

I would appreciate a proper explanation for one of the examples, or even a totally different address, I want to understand how to do it properly.

Comment: You've got examples in textbooks on OSes, numerous CS course websites. Even [youtube videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vw1B-U0Frws). What more do you need?

Comment: Please stop reposting this question.